# Removing the Scrollbar from Horizontal List

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I've got an Horizontal List. It contains 6 XML Nodes at the moment. But what I'd like to do is remove the scrollbar so that an button can function to scroll through the nodes instead.

Has anyone achieved this, if so how did you go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually remove the scroll bar by setting the [horizontalScrollPolicy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#horizontalScrollPolicy) or [verticalScrollPolicy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#verticalScrollPolicy) to off.

After that, I believe you can scroll the list by setting the [verticalScrollPosition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#verticalScrollPosition) or [horizontalScrollPosition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/ScrollControlBase.html#horizontalScrollPosition)